# Use of unresolved identifier - app development with Swift Project 2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, identifier

Sorry - I realise this is a complete beginner question, but I've googled for half a day now and still can't resolve the issue myself.

I'm using xCode 8.3 and trying to complete the apple - app development with swift course - end of unit project 2. I'm told (by the Apple book) I should be able to run the app without build failures, even if it isn't finished.

I get an unresolved identifier error when I add the following code to my ViewControler file, inside the class ViewController: UIViewController.

```
func updateUI() {
    correctWordLabel.text = game.formattedWord
    scoreLabel.text = "Wins: \(totalWins), Losses: \(totalLosses)"
    treeImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Tree \(currentGame.incorrectMovesRemaining)")
}
```

xCode suggests I change it to Game.formattedWord, but when i do get 'Instance member 'formattedWord' cannot be used on type 'Game' ViewController.Swift'.

Could someone please help?

I've checked the sample code from Apple about 100 times and they are def saying it should be game.formattedWord in the code.

Thank you!

Comment: This is the code from the Game.Swift file.

Comment: Inside the struct Game...
    var formattedWord: String {
        var guessedWord = ""
        for letter in word.characters {
            if guessedLetters.contains(letter) {
                guessedWord += "\(letter)"
            } else {
                guessedWord += "_"
            }
        }
        return guessedWord

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `correctWordLabel.text = currentGame.formattedWord`
I think it’s a typo.
Earlier in your code you create an instance of the Game struct called `currentGame` so you are accessing the formattedWord variable inside that instance. That’s why you couldn’t change it to Game. Game is like the blueprint of the struct. currentGame is your actual ‘thing’ Hope that makes some sense.

Comment: Hi Magnas... worked perfectly, and makes sense... Thank you for taking the time for answering :)

Comment: Glad to help. Would you mind accepting the answer? The more rep I accumulate, the more the site allows me to do. Not ego related, honest.

Comment: Sorry! Only the second time I've posted on here... just accepted. It won't let me upvote it because I'm a newbie.